# How to ident a relational model

Tags: spacing

[image: goal]

Hi, i would like to make an  relational model   and would like to follow this notation. What is the best way to achive it

Comment: Should the eventual output align with the left margin, or be centred on the page (horizontally)? And how big would you want this type of construction (you use "...", but is it typically a couple of lines, or does it span pages)? Should it be allowed to flow across the page boundary (if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably work with the following setup - an `array` with some predefined formatting setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\PK}[1]{\underline{\var{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FK}[1]{\textup{FK}(#1)}

\newenvironment{relationalmodel}
  {\par\medskip
   \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}%
   $\begin{array}{ r l }}
   {\end{array}$
   \par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{relationalmodel}
  \var{table}_1( &
    \PK{column}_2, \var{column}_3, \var{column}_4, \ldots ) \\
  & \var{column}_2 : \FK{\var{table}_2} \\
  & \var{column}_3, \var{column}_4 : \FK{\var{table}_3} \\
  & \ldots
\end{relationalmodel}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: What `environ`?

Comment: You cheater! ;-)